# MySQL Error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

Я новичок в SQL. Пытаюсь составить несложный запрос и получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'q2 order by title' at line 1
```

В гугле нашел, что это связано с неправильным использованием кавычек, но у меня их вообще нету и не знаю должны ли быть. И вообще в разных местах причина такой ошибки указывается разная. Прошу помощи. Вот запрос:

```
SELECT title, name_author, name_genre, price, amount FROM book 
INNER JOIN author ON book.author_id = author.author_id 
INNER JOIN genre ON book.genre_id = genre.genre_id 
WHERE book.genre_id IN (SELECT q1.genre_id, MAX(q1.sum_amount)
FROM (SELECT genre_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount 
FROM book GROUP BY genre_id)q1 GROUP BY genre_id)q2 ORDER BY title;
```

Поскольку это вроде как синтаксическая ошибка надеюсь, что схема таблиц не нужна. Спасибо.

Comment: Если почистить, получится `SELECT .. WHERE book.genre_id IN ( .. )q2 ORDER BY title;`. Ну и за каким тут `q2`?

Comment: Пока делаю как могу

Comment: Форматирование кода не требует знаний.

Comment: Не согласен. На первых порах пишешь, чтобы работало вообще хоть как-то. У меня так. Иначе на форматирование уходит лишнее внимание, а его стараешься бросить на решение задачи. Тем более, что я писал этот запрос по примеру и не знал, что можно проще.

Comment: Если писать с нормальным форматированием то ошибки видны гораздо легче. Совершенно ничего не стоит расставить переносы и отступы.

Comment: схема таблиц, возможно и не нужна, зато смысл того что вы хотите найти этим запросом - очень даже пригодилось бы.

Comment: Катитесь в жопу, стаковерфловеры :)

Comment: Бараны стадные.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ваш запрос выглядит неполным, и, возможно, вам нужно использовать подзапрос q2 с оператором JOIN для объединения результатов. Кроме того, в MySQL нельзя использовать MAX в SELECT в сочетании с другими столбцами без использования GROUP BY.

Попробуйте следующий запрос:

```
SELECT title, name_author, name_genre, price, amount
FROM book
INNER JOIN author ON book.author_id = author.author_id
INNER JOIN genre ON book.genre_id = genre.genre_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT q1.genre_id, MAX(q1.sum_amount) AS max_amount
    FROM (
        SELECT genre_id, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount 
        FROM book 
        GROUP BY genre_id
    ) q1
    GROUP BY q1.genre_id
) q2 ON book.genre_id = q2.genre_id AND book.amount = q2.max_amount
ORDER BY title;
```

Comment: вы пытались понять, что делает запрос? Вот вы на самом вложенном уровне вбыираете жарны и общее количество книг этого жанра. То есть у вас N строк по N жанрам. Далее вы наворачиваете max, который выдаст ровно то же самое значеие, которое уже посчитанно суммой т.к. в каждой группе только одна строка.
Потом вы лепите это к книгам, пытаясь найти книгу такого жанра где с числом экземпляров равным этомум максимуму из суммы. Иными словами говоря, Автор судя по всему хотел найти перечень книг, из жанра с максимальным количеством книг, а ваш запрос выведет книги, которые единственны в своем жанре.